# Request for principal permission failed when working with multiple assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, security, principal

I have a simple application split into three assemblies. One is a client form that allows user to read a key from the registry. Second is an authorization form through which the user logs in. The third is a .dll library with all the methods doing the actual work.

I followed MSDN tutorial on Performing Declarative Security Checks found here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dswfd229.aspx but something still doesn' work.

I create GenericPrincipal object like this:

```
    public static void CreatePrincipal(string user)
    {
        GenericIdentity MyIdentity = new GenericIdentity(user);

        String[] MyString = { "Administrator", "User" };

        GenericPrincipal MyPrincipal =
            new GenericPrincipal(MyIdentity, MyString);

        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = MyPrincipal;
    }
```

This is located in the CustomPrincipal class in the .dll assembly.

In the same assembly I have a RegistryOperations class with the following method:

```
    [PrincipalPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "admin1", Role = "User")]
    public static string ReadDeclarative()
    {
      ...
    }
```

Nothing fancy. In my "Authorization" assembly I have the GUI which calls for .dll method for authorization:

```
    private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CustomPrincipal.CreatePrincipal(txtUsername.Text);
    }
```

Finally in the third, "Client" assembly I call for the .dll method to read registry keys:

```
    private void btnReadRegistry_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtContents.Text = RegistryOperations.ReadDeclarative();
    }
```

This doesn't work. I login in through the Authorization assembly and when I try to read the registry **I get the Request for principal permission failed.** Visual Studio suggests adding the assemblies to some mystical Full Trust list but that is nowehere to be found in VS2010. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

When you log in, are you using the user name `admin1`?  (If you weren't intending to check for a matching user name in the permission verification, you should remove it from the demand.)

Comment: I did intent to check for a matching user name for the testing purposes. I am logging in with the 'admin1' user name, so that's not it :(

Comment: In that case, I cannot repro.  Have you tried adding code to the btnReadRegistry_Click method to verify the contents of Thread.CurrentPrincipal at the time it is executed?

Comment: Yes, I've checked it with a debugger. Contents are there.